# Adding new Column(s) to a dataframe based on value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've read many questions about this, but I couldnt figure out how to apply those solutions to my own problem. I figure I have to use `df.apply` or `df.assign` but I don't understand how even after reading the documentation

This is my data:

```
d = {'switchopen': [True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, True ],
     'switchclose': [ False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

It's open when `switchopen == True & switchclose == False`

It's closed when `switchopen == False & switchclose == True`

it's moving when `switchopen == False & switchclose == False`

My current solution is this:

```
dfopen = df[(df.switchclose == False) & (df.switchopen == True)]
dfopen['Open'] = 'open'
dfclose = df[(df.switchclose == True) & (df.switchopen == False)]
dfclose['Moving'] = 'close'
dfmoving = df[(df.switchclose == False) & (df.switchopen == False)]
dfmoving['Close'] = 'moving'

dfs = [dfopen, dfclose, dfmoving]
dfz = pd.concat(dfs, sort= False)
dfz = dfz.sort_index(ascending=True)

dfz['Position'] = dfz['Position'].fillna(dfz['Open'])
dfz['Position'] = dfz['Position'].fillna(dfz['Close'])
print(dfz['Position'])
```

Which gives me what I want but i am looking for a better solution like:

```
df['Close'] = (df.switchclose == True & df.switchopen == False)
df['Open'] = (df.switchclose == False & df.switchopen == False)
df['Moving'] = (df.switchclose == False & df.switchopen == False)
```

And then use the `.fillna`.

it would be best if there was a solution where that step wouldn't even be necesary

The expected output is this:

```
       Position
0       open
1       open
2     moving
3     moving
4     moving
5      close
6      close
7      close
8      close
9      close
10    moving
11    moving
12    moving
13      open
14      open
15    moving
16    moving
17      open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your logical requirements and output expectations, this should work

```
df.loc[(df['switchopen'] == True) & (df['switchclose'] == False), 'Position'] = 'open'
df.loc[(df['switchopen'] == False) & (df['switchclose'] == True), 'Position'] = 'closed'
df.loc[(df['switchopen'] == False) & (df['switchclose'] == False), 'Position'] = 'moving'
```

Comment: Such an easy solution, I feel dumb that I didn't think of using `df.loc`. I'll accept this is in 2mins

Comment: Glad I could help ;) @MartijnvanAmsterdam

Comment: The booleans are unnecessary, the data already contains booleans. No need to add them to use logical operators

Answer (score 1):

For multiple conditions you can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). You can start by defining the conditions:

```
c1 = df.switchopen & ~df.switchclose
c2 = ~df.switchopen & df.switchclose
c3 = ~df.switchopen & ~df.switchclose
```

And on the right term specify the `choicelist` from which the output elements are taken:

```
df['position'] = np.select([c1,c2, c3], ['open','closed', 'moving'])

     switchopen  switchclose position
0         True        False     open
1         True        False     open
2        False        False   moving
3        False        False   moving
4        False        False   moving
5        False         True   closed
6        False         True   closed
7        False         True   closed
8        False         True   closed
9        False         True   closed
10       False        False   moving
11       False        False   moving
12       False        False   moving
13        True        False     open
14        True        False     open
15       False        False   moving
16       False        False   moving
17        True        False     open
```

Answer (score 0):

I like np.where. Here is the solution with it:

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[:,'position1'] = np.where((df['switchopen'] == True) & (df['switchclose'] == False), 'open',
                        np.where((df['switchopen'] == False) & (df['switchclose'] == True), 'closed',
                        np.where((df['switchopen'] == False) & (df['switchclose'] == False), 'moving',
                                np.nan)))
```

As you can see, you can set the NaN for neither of the conditionals.